# Package my python project into exe file that requires nothing to be installed on customer side

Tags: python, conda, pyinstaller, pyenv, python-poetry

I have developed a python application that records the users' actions on the web using the following packages

```
python==3.7.9
selenium==4.0.0
seleniumbase==2.1.9
Tinkerer==1.7.2
tqdm==4.62.3
validators==0.18.2
```

I have tried to use a lot of different approaches to convert into an exe file **that will require nothing to be installed on the client's side**
I have tried using the following

1. `pyvan` and it did not work and I opened an issue to the pkg's author
2. `pyinstaller` and when I run my code, it always tells me that the library `SeleniumBase` is unknown and the solution is to install it on the customer side **WHICH IS NOT AN OPTION**
3. `pipenv` and did not work as well
4. `PyOxidizer` & `py2exe` did not work with me as well

> I would like to convert that python application into an `exe` (I don't care if it is a single file or folder) as long as it requires no installation on the user's side

Repo Structure

```
├── requirements.txt
├── main.py
├── logo.ico
├── web_actions_recorder
|   ├── main.py
|   ├── __init__.py
└── README.md
```

Comment: "application that records the users' actions on the web <...> will require nothing to be installed on the client's side" - this sounds illegal

Comment: Looks like this package could help overcome the missing Selenium installation: https://pypi.org/project/webdrivermanager/

Comment: 'I want to interract with the client's web browser without installing anything'.  Sadly windoze is sufficiently broken there are probably ways to do that, but *why* do you want to do such an invasive thing?  Note generally that python -> exe is a fragile process: python is a scripting language, and bundled installs have a tendency to fail in corner cases.  Windows defender will also block them.

Comment: To fix the pyinstaller issue, you can specify seleniumbase as a hidden import with `--hidden-import` or explicitly import it in your code. However, `selenium` is generally not capable of doing what you describe; it can't be attached to a user's normal web browser without sufficient intervention. It also always requires that a compatible browser be installed, of which you won't know the version ahead of time. This sounds (1) a bit shady and (2) not feasible as described. The proper way to monitor user activity (say, in a corporate environment) is through a network MITM inspection proxy.

Comment: Just to clarify things, the user will be notified with the recordings done on their computer(s). Not to mention this an automation tool being is developed based on the client’s request. 

I am using Selenium & SeleniumBase which do record the interaction of the user with their browser, to be automated later on.

Comment: I have used —hidden-imports with pyinstaller, yet when I ran the produced exe file (using PyInstaller) it basically throws the same exception “seleniumbase is unknown”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution/workaround

My application has this line where I am trying to invoke SeleniumBase on the customer side by the following python snippet `import os; os.system("sbase mkrec recording.py")` which is not possible as the customer does not have `seleniumbase` on his/her PC

The solution is as follows:

1. Copy from your env Python Folder `C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38` and paste it inside your project files.

   - The folder is called Python38 as I am working with multiple python versions on my PC, this one is named Python38 as it is python version 3.8.10
2. Edit the code to be as following

```
import os


# the script was in a folder so I had to do `os.path.dirname(".") first
python_dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("."), "Python38", "python.exe")
# in that way we will use the python folder with everything installed in
# to help us run the `sbase` command without having to install 
# anything on the user's side 
os.system(f"{python_path} -m sbase mkrec recording.py")
```

3. Finally use `PyInstaller v4.7` to package the application, in my case
   `pyinstaller --clean --onedir --name <your_app_name> --windowed --hidden-import seleniumbase --icon <path_to_icon> main.py`